# Mysql concat query not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

This query did not update the table in Mysql database:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users 
SET friend_array=CONCAT(users.friend_array,'$user_to') 
WHERE username='$user_from'");
```

Comment: Any error showing up?

Comment: Did you get a php error? Also post table schema.

Comment: See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: If 'friend' (or indeed, anything) is an array, then something's gone very wrong here. See normalisation. And STOP using PHP's mysql_ API

Comment: friend_array is the name of column. while "users" is the name of table. the datatype of friend_array is varchar. the inserted values are strings which concates with the old strings values

Comment: Yes. I rather suspected (feared) it might be. Fix that, or don't bother using an RDBMS. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Hi From given info I can say only that add this `die(mysql_error());` after `execution` of `query` this will give you your error.
Also add these two lines at the top of your `php` file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

mysql_query("UPDATE users 
SET friend_array=CONCAT(users.friend_array,'$user_to') 
WHERE username='$user_from'") or die(mysql_error());
```

And Please don't use `mysql`it is `deprecated` now instead use `mysqli` or other

Comment: This rather ignores the elephant in the room.